# vscode 1.8x language extension -- why isn't my hover window expandable

Tags: hover, vscode-extensions

since vscode 1.8x, hover windows can be expanded -- very helpful when a function signature plus its docs are somewhat verbose....  hovers in typescript, python, etc all now have this capability....

in supporting my own language, i also have hover popups which show function signatures, docs, etc....  but for some reason, these popup windows are **NOT** expandable....  including a very long line in the window always wraps; and grabbing the window's edge doesn't allow further horizontal sizing....  FWIW, i don't see any scrollbars in my popup windows -- unlike what i see when hovering in a typescript or python source file....

the hover content (a `MarkdownString`) is largely produced through a call to `appendCodeblock`, which uses the same mechanisms supporting syntax highlighting in the editor....  in some cases, additional calls to `appendMarkdown` are present....

debugging (or even viewing!!!) the HTML within the popup window is a bit challenging using the Developer Tools -- keeping focus on the popup while switching windows is quite tricky!!!!

thoughts on how i might approach this problem????

Comment: to add one more detail, the popup window **IS** resizable in the vertical dimension -- just not horizontally....  it's as if "word wrap" is being applied to the content -- automatically breaking lines the don't fit the popup window's default width....